# Django i18n routing doesn't work properly for app urls

Tags: python, django, internationalization

This is my structure

```
core/
    locale/
        en
        it
shopping/
    urls.py
locale/
    en
    it
store/
    locale/
        en
        it
    urls.py
    settings.py
```

The locale folder outside the shopping app contains somehow the translations for shopping. The store has the main url routing:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', views.HomepageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('shopping/', include('shopping.urls', namespace='shopping')),
    path('despreNoi/', views.DespreNoi.as_view(), name='despreNoi'),
    path('profil/', views.Profil.as_view() ,  name='profil'),
]


urlpatterns += i18n_patterns (
    path('', views.HomepageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    path('contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('despreNoi/', views.DespreNoi.as_view(), name='despreNoi'),
    path('profil/', views.Profil.as_view() ,  name='profil'),
    path('shopping/', include('shopping.urls'), name='shopping'),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

After executing the

> python manage.py makemessages --all

and

> python manage.py compilemessages

If I go from an /it or /en page to a page routed in shopping's urls.py then it doesn't recognize the language and goes to the default page.
This is my settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
)

prefix_default_language = False

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/locale/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)
```

UPDATE: I think that the issue is that in my templates I access the urls like this

```
<li><a href="{% url 'shopping:productList' %}">Products</a></li>
```

How can I use the url tag to not change the language?